# Fail to create a folder in android app with NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, manifest

While running the app on the emulator, system reports an error while cpp code trying to create a directory in folder "/home/cocadas/Workspace/android-project/JNIAppSample".

Java will call a JNI cpp function to create the directory.

The cpp source code is as following:

```
static int createEventDir(void)
{
  int    result;
  int    stringLen;
  time_t currentTime = time(0);
  struct tm * now = localtime(&currentTime);

  stringLen = sprintf(thisEventParms.eventDirectory,
                      ADAN_EVENT_BASE_DIR, now->tm_mon + 1,
                        now->tm_mday,        now->tm_hour,
                        now->tm_min,         now->tm_sec);

  if (stringLen > 0)
  {
    result = mkdir(thisEventParms.eventDirectory, 0700);
  }
  else
  {
    // TBD: Error, unable to make event directory
    result = -1;
  }
  return(result);
}
```

Android Studio debug reports ​result = -1 after executing result = mkdir(thisEventParms.eventDirectory, 0700);​ Also, debug reports thisEventParms.eventDirectory = "/home/cocadas/Workspace/android-project/JNIAppSample", which is expected.

After some research, I add one permission in manifest like the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

But it still gives result = -1

Any comment or suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App's path for external storage in native code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19568354/608639)

Answer (score 3):

I guess that the android emulator has the same structure as any android device.

So, /home/cocadas...etc doesn't exist in your emulator.

If the response is -1, usually seems that your path is not writable.

In conclusion, writable path could be "/sdcard/your_directory." and of course you will need to add the permission you written above.

If you want to get an writable path but inside of your apk use this code.

```
String config_path=m_context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().toString();
```

Cheers.

Comment: thanks! I tried the method. It successfully returns an directory.